# Is this proof valid?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, solution-verification, alternative-proof, hyperbolic-functions

I have a function $\;g(x)-x\;$ on the domain $\;0<x<\frac{1}{3}\;$, where

$g(x)=\frac{\left(9 x^2+1\right) \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{36 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)}{\left(9 x^2+1\right)^2}\right) \sqrt{81 x^4+54 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)+1}}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi  \cosh (\pi  x)}+\frac{18 \sqrt{2} x^2 \left(9 \pi  x^3+4 \tanh (\pi  x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi }.$

I want to prove that $\;g(x)-x\neq 0\;$, or if possible, prove that it is always greater than zero $\;g(x)-x>0\;$ (I know this by numerical data).

**Proof:**
Assuming the proposition to be false, I have

$g(x)\leq x \quad Eq. (1)$.

On the other hand, values of $\;g(x)\;$ at the endpoints of the domain are as follows:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \, g(x)=0 \quad and \quad \lim_{x\to \frac{1}{3}} \, g(x)=1.33$

Now, considering the equal sign in Eq. (1) for $\;x=\frac{1}{3}\;$, we get $\;1.33=\frac{1}{3}\;$ which is a contradiction. If the inequality sign holds in (1), it gives the range of $\;g(x)\;$ as $\;(0,\frac{1}{3})\;$, while from the limit above, we see that $\;g(\frac{1}{3})=1.33\;$ which is greater than $\;\frac{1}{3}\;$.

**Question:** Are these arguments sufficient to conclude that the proposition $\;g(x)\leq x\;$ is false and $\;g(x)-x\;$ is always greater than zero? Or, the argument only brings a counterexample and it is not sufficient as proof.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: How did you come across this scary-looking function?

Comment: @JairTaylor It is part of another proof. I am thinking about it for more than one week.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument does not work.

Your proposition is that *for all* $x$ with $0<x<1/3$ we have $g(x)-x>0$. Assuming it to be false would be to say *there exists* a $x$ with $0<x<1/3$ and $g(x)-x\leq 0$.

I.e under the assumption that the proposition is false we can have $g(x)-x>0$ for all $x$ with $0<x<1/3$ except one

Comment: Thanks. How about the argument about $g(x)\neq x$. If I can prove only this part, it is sufficient for the problem I have.

Comment: If you know that your function $g(x)$ is continuous on the interval $(0,1/3)$, and manage to prove that $g(x)\ne x$ on this interval , then indeed you are correct! Because you cannot have points $a$ and $b$ with $g(a)-a>0$ and $g(b)-b<0$ as then, by the intermediate value theorem applied to $g(x)-x$,  there would need to be a point $c$ in between $a$ and $b$ with $g(c)-c=0$.